# Noise in switching regulator

Tags: dc-dc-converter

what is meant by low frequency noise in a DC to DC converters that the vendors claim for switching regulators? What is the frequency range?

Comment: Can you reference a specific example? It might also be useful to understand something about your application (are you designing an audio product, or struggling with some cruft you bought on ebay for 0.$?)

Answer (score 1):

Under light load, certain regulators can enter PFM mode which consists of varying the frequency of a pulse. If the load is light enough, the regulator will only need to supply a few (comparatively) pulses per second. This can induce low frequency noise though I'd imagine the frequency is load dependent.

The Microchip TC105 for example is a buck converter which switches between PWM and PFM mode for light load conditions - defined as duty cycles less than 10%.